# python: integrating a piecewise function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I want to integrate a piecewise a defined function that is multiplied by the Legendre polynomials.
Unfortunately, I can't find how to use the nth Legendre polynomial of x in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.legendre.html).  I want to integrate each Legendre polynomial of x when `n = 1,..., 50` so I have set `n = np.arange(1, 51, 1)`.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy import integrate

n = np.arange(1, 51, 1)                                                   


def f(x):
    if 0 <= x <= 1:
        return 1
    if -1 <= x <= 0:
        return -1
```

I suppose I need to define another function let's say `u(x)`.

```
c = []


def u(x):
    c.append((2. * n + 1) / 2. * integrate.quad(f(x) * insert Legendre polynomials here, -1., 1.)) 
    return sum(c * Legendre poly, for nn in range(1, 51))
```

So I would then return some `u(x)` with the first 50 terms expanding my piecewise function by Legendre polynomials.

**Edit 1:**

If this can't be done, I could use Rodrigues's Formula to compute the nth Legendre polynomial.  However, I couldn't find anything useful when I was looking for computing nth derivatives in Python.

```
P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2 - 1)^n
```

So this is an option if someone knows how to implement such a scheme in Python.

**Edit 2:**

Using Saullo Castro's answer, I have:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def f(x, coef):
    global p
    p = np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre(coef=coef)
    if 0 <= x <= 1:
        return 1*p(x)
    if -1 <= x <= 0:
        return -1*p(x)

c = []
for n in range(1, 51):
    c.append((2. * n + 1.) / 2. * quad(f, -1, 1, args=range(1,n+1))[0])

def g(x)
    return sum(c * p(x) for n in range(1, 51))
```

However, if I print `c`, the values are wrong.  The values should be `1.5, 0, -7/8, 0, ...`

Also, when I plot `g`, I would like to do `x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 500000)` so the plot is detailed but `c` is only 50.  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to calculate the integral of f(x) * Ln(x) where f(x) is a piecewise function you're defining with a python function.  I'm assuming you're not specifically interested in this particular step function.

You can get the values of the Legendre polynomials using [legval](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.legval.html#numpy.polynomial.legendre.legval) with the identity matrix for the coefficient argument.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 201)

L = np.polynomial.legendre.legval(x, np.identity(50))

plt.plot(x, L.T)
```

[image]

You can then perform the integral with quadrature.  Using gauss-legendre quadrature might be more efficient since the integral of a legendre polynomial will be exact for Ln(x) where n is less than the quadrature size.

```
import numpy as np    
from numpy.polynomial.legendre import leggauss, legval

def f(x):
    if 0 <= x <= 1:
        return 1
    if -1 <= x <= 0:
        return -1

# of course you could write a vectorized version of
# this particular f(x), but I assume you have a more
# general piecewise function
f = np.vectorize(f)

deg = 100
x, w = leggauss(deg) # len(x) == 100

L = np.polynomial.legendre.legval(x, np.identity(deg))
# Sum L(xi)*f(xi)*wi
integral = (L*(f(x)*w)[None,:]).sum(axis=1)

c = (np.arange(1,51) + 0.5) * integral[1:51]

x_fine = np.linspace(-1, 1, 2001) # 2001 points
Lfine = np.polynomial.legendre.legval(x_fine, np.identity(51))

# sum_1_50 of c(n) * Ln(x_fine)
cLn_sum = (c[:,None] * Lfine[1:51,:]).sum(axis=0)
```

c = 1.5, 0, -8.75e-1, 0, ... which I think is the result you're looking for.

Comment: How can plot `sum(c * p(x) for n in range(1, 51))` where `p(x)` is the Legendre polynomial or order n?

Comment: The rows of L contain L(x) starting with L0 in the first row.  You do the sum and plot them.

Comment: The problem I am having is we don't have an n to sum over so how can I sum?

Comment: I don't really understand "we don't have an n to sum over."  The nth row of L represents the value of Ln(x) where each column corresponds to a different value of x.  I.e., L[n, i] == Ln(x[i]).  I've modified the answer to show how to get this sum in numpy.  You could also just write a loop.  At this point, I'm a little confused about what you're trying to accomplish, but I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sure you can recalculate L with finer x spacing.  There's two ways to do that.  You could just increase the degree you use for the integration, which will increase the quadrature points.  You can also recalculate L with finer spacing, which I did above.  I didn't check to see if the integrate converged, so you may want to increase deg and see if there's any change.

Comment: I figure out increasing deg worked thanks.  I have new question related to this code if you want to check it out too.

Answer (score 3):

You can do your integration like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def f(x, coef):
    n = coef[-1]
    p = (2*n+1)/2.*np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre(coef=coef)
    if 0 <= x <= 1:
        return 1*p(x)
    if -1 <= x <= 0:
        return -1*p(x)

c = []
for n in range(1, 51):
    c.append(quad(f, -1, 1, args=range(1,n+1))[0])
```

And this gives:

```
print c
#[0.0, 5.0, 6.9999999999999991, 4.5, ... , 62.975635570615466, 64.274102283412574, 77.143785770271251]
```

Comment: Something isn't write.  The first coefficient should be `1.5` but this prints `0, 5, 7, 4.5, ..`  Also, you will get something slightly different since I forgot to put (2.*n + 1.)/2. in front of the integration in my first post.  So I have `c.append((2. * n + 1.) / 2. * quad(f, -1, 1, args=range(1,n+1))[0])`

Comment: Is this integrating `n`?  If so, that would be the problem.  I need to integrate over `x`

Comment: Actually, it is integrating `x` from `-1` to `+1`. (See `quad` documentation here)[http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html]. The integrand was wrong in my answer, now I fixed it and it is giving the expected result for `c`...