# Python: heat density plot in a disk

Tags: python, matplotlib, sum

My goal is to make a density heat map plot of sphere in 2D.  The plotting code below the line works when I use rectangular domains.  However, I am trying to use the code for a circular domain.  The radius of sphere is 1.  The code I have so far is:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
from numpy.polynomial.legendre import leggauss, legval

xi = 0.0
xf = 1.0
numx = 500

yi = 0.0
yf = 1.0
numy = 500


def f(x):
    if 0 <= x <= 1:
        return 100
    if -1 <= x <= 0:
        return 0


deg = 1000
xx, w = leggauss(deg)
L = np.polynomial.legendre.legval(xx, np.identity(deg))
integral = (L * (f(x) * w)[None,:]).sum(axis = 1)

c = (np.arange(1, 500) + 0.5) * integral[1:500]


def r(x, y):
    return np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)


theta = np.arctan2(y, x)
x, y = np.linspace(0, 1, 500000)


def T(x, y):
    return (sum(r(x, y) ** l * c[:,None] *
                np.polynomial.legendre.legval(xx, identity(deg)) for l in range(1, 500)))
```

`T(x, y)` should equal the sum of `c` the coefficients times the radius as a function of `x` and `y` to the `l` power times the legendre polynomial where the argument is of the legendre polynomial is `cos(theta)`.

In [python: integrating a piecewise function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144554/python-integrating-a-piecewise-function/19145411#19145411), I learned how to use the Legendre polynomials in a summation but that method is slightly different, and for the plotting, I need a function `T(x, y)`.

---

This is the plotting code.

```
densityinterpolation = 'bilinear'
densitycolormap = cm.jet
densityshadedflag = False
densitybarflag = True
gridflag = True
plotfilename = 'laplacesphere.eps'

x = arange(xi, xf, (xf - xi) / (numx - 1))
y = arange(yi, yf, (yf - yi) / (numy - 1))
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
z = T(X, Y)


if densityshadedflag:
    ls = LightSource(azdeg = 120, altdeg = 65)
    rgb = ls.shade(z, densitycolormap)
    im = imshow(rgb, extent = [xi, xf, yi, yf], cmap = densitycolormap)
else:
    im = imshow(z, extent = [xi, xf, yi, yf], cmap = densitycolormap)
im.set_interpolation(densityinterpolation)
if densitybarflag:
    colorbar(im)


grid(gridflag)

show()
```

I made the plot in Mathematica for reference of what my end goal is
[image]

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but the way the phrasing is so wrapped up in Legendre polynomials, etc, it's difficult to figure out what you're really asking.  Do you just want to know how to make a heatmap on a disk?  That seems interesting.  If so, maybe you could delete this question and ask another that focuses just on that.

Comment: @tom10 I would like to know how to make a heat map on a disk. Additionally, I don't fully understand how I would enforce the summation of Legendre polynomials since I just learned how to use it and don't fully understand it the set up of the function.

Comment: Maybe "heat map on a disk" and "enforce summation of Legendre polynomials" might possibly be better of as separate questions?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the values outside of the disk domain (or whichever domain you want) to float('nan'), those points will be ignored when plotting (leaving them in white color).